# How to encode a linebreak in XML

Tags: html, xml, newline

I have XML elements that contain text with newlines but no other formatting.  The text is being read by javascript and displayed in HTML.  Is there an XML-safe way to encode the linebreak, or does this text need to be CDATA?

**Example:**

```
<sample>Here is a line <br>Here is another</sample>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

needs to be CDATA:

```
<sample><![CDATA[Here is a line <br />Here is another]]></sample>
```

Comment: Thanks- btw your CDATA is missing a closing bracket